Deploy ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API to IIS in development system is not working
The ASP.NET Core 6.0 Web API published local folder and configured to IIS for testing is not working. The same Web API works with dotnet dll name.

This site can't be reached - localhost refused to connect.

I have already tried:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Steps followed

Installed IIS in local
Installed .NET hosting bundle 6.0.3
Configure web API to IIS as site.
Tried to connect to Web API by browsing option in IIS action pane.

I'm still getting the error.
If I comment out the following lines, it works
       app.UseHsts();
       app.UseHttpsRedirection();

I want to simulate the server environment and test it in local
What should be done to do HTTPS binding here?


Likely that you forgot to configure an HTTPS binding for this site, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics#background

Thanks for the input, I did binding for https and it works.  Hostname can be given if we have any valid domain purchased.  can we use application name as hostname in local for testing ?

Did you assign a self-signed certificate to your https site?
